# Align CSS element to bottom-left, but still take up space

Tags: css

I have a set of `<div>` elements that need to have timestamps at the end.

```html
<dl class="container">
   <dd time="5:30 PM">some text</dd>
   <dd time="5:35 PM">possibly very long text that takes up more than one line, long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</dd>
   <dd time="5:44 PM">or short</dd>
</dl>
```

The timestamps are being created with the `::after` pseudo. I need them to take up space within the box, so they can't be `absolute`, but they need to cling to the bottom left corner.

- Float doesn't let me align to the bottom.
- Because it's a pseudo I can't double-wrap it, and moreover I'd really prefer to avoid that, if at all possible.
- If I could get the `::after` to take up the remaining width in the last line, then I could just right-align the text and it'd be fine, but I haven't been able to find any way to make an element take up the remaining space in the last line of a paragraph of text.
- `block`, `table-footer-group` and `table-caption` create a new line, and **I want the timestamp to be on the same line, if there's space for it there.**
- Maybe there's a flex-box solution, but what I've tried so far always seems to mess up the paragraph of text above

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution One:

Apply `display:block` to the `dd::after` element:

```css
dd{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

dd::after {
  content: attr(time);
  display: block;
  margin-top:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<dl class="container">
   <dd time="5:30 PM">some text</dd>
   <dd time="5:35 PM">possibly very long text that takes up more than one line, long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</dd>
   <dd time="5:44 PM">or short</dd>
</dl>
```

You could also do this by including special character "`\A`" in content, and set `white-space: pre-wrap`, but you'd still need to set display to block if you want to use margins or padding:

```css
dd{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  background-color:lightblue;
}
dd::after {
  content:"\A " attr(time);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<dl class="container">
   <dd time="5:30 PM">some text</dd>
   <dd time="5:35 PM">possibly very long text that takes up more than one line, long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</dd>
   <dd time="5:44 PM">or short</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that flexbox was a problem.

This seems to resolve it but it is the same as setting the pseudo-element to `display:block` as mentioned in the other answer.

```css
dd {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

dd:after {
  content: attr(time);
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<dl class="container">
  <dd time="5:30 PM">some text</dd>
  <dd time="5:35 PM">possibly very long text that takes up more than one line, long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</dd>
  <dd time="5:44 PM">or short</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't want it to take up a full line. I only want it to take up as much width as it needs.